# Undefined reference to curl objects

Tags: c++, curl, linker, codeblocks

(EDITED) I'm trying to get curl to call information from a webpage for weeks and I get the seemingly common error where my program is unable to identify curl objects:

```
C:/Users/.../CurlAttempt/CurlAttempt1.cpp:25: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_global_init'
C:/Users/.../CurlAttempt/CurlAttempt1.cpp:26: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_init'
C:/Users/.../CurlAttempt/CurlAttempt1.cpp:28: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've followed the instructions from this tutorial on how to link the library to the compiler to a tee:

> Download the 'Win32 Generic' libcurl package. (7.24.0)
>
> In Code::Blocks, right click your project and open the build options.
>
> Go to 'Linker Settings' and add 'curldll' into the 'Link Libraries'
>   listbox.
>
> Go to 'Search Directories' and under 'Compiler' link it to the path of
>   your 'curl-7.24.0-devel-mingw32\include' folder.
>
> Go to the 'Linker' tab under 'Search Directories', and add the path of
>   your 'curl-7.24.0-devel-mingw32\lib' directory.
>
> Move all DLLs from your 'curl-7.24.0-devel-mingw32\bin' folder into
>   your projects 'bin' folder.
>
> Build and enjoy

I've been working on this for a week and I'm getting nowhere. CURL tutorials are either outdated or not pertaining to calling data from a url. I'm trying to get my libraries linked and recognized. Yes I have my compiler following the file path to my libcurl.a and libcrul.dll.a lib folder files.

I'm using Windows 10 and Code blocks IDE just like the tutorial. (With one more reputation point I can embed images of the file path).

Comment: try `-lcurl` or `-lC:/path/to/libcurl.lib`

Comment: tried the 'curl' command in the linker. Seems to have worked. Running into undefined references issues again, tho.

Comment: show us? https://gist.github.com/

Comment: Yes. I'm editing the question above. Although I need 1 more reputation point to embed images so I'll be right back.